# Magento 2.3.2 Inventory Reservation, adding entries for open order before inventory upgrade

Tags: sales-order, magento2.3.2, magento-upgrade, multi-source-inventory, msi

My salable quantity is off.

I figured out why it's off and how salable quantity is calculated.

Example proper order:

User: New order with product sku SKU-AAA x 1

System: Create a Reservation for SKU-AAA x 1...

table `inventory_reservation` fields `reservation_id,stock_id,sku,quantity,metadata`

```
1 1 SKU-AAA -1.0000 {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"12345"}
```

After Shipped...

System: Counter the Reservation... (and cleaned by cron later on)

```
2 1 SKU-AAA 1.0000 {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"12345"}
```

System: Finally deduct the physical quantity of the SKU-AAA.

My problem is that I have orders that are still open, and are made before the new inventory system!

I also know that I have to somehow manually create those missing reservation entries, but I was hoping that there is a built-in way of doing that...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you had fixed this, if not check the CLI commands to check and resolve reservation inconsistencies.

https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/CLI-Reference